# S3 default public ACL fot object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

Is there any ways to upload/update object in s3 with defaults public-read ACL?

I know that we have f.e

`aws s3 cp /path/to/file s3://sample_bucket --acl public-read`

but here we can specify only one obj, and actualy it is does not work if I'll upload same file again

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? If you want to make all objects public, you should use a Bucket Policy rather than updating each object. In fact, these days it is recommend that ACLs are deactivated. See: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I need to have constant access via the web to objects in c3, even after the update.
Unfortunately, this policy does not work as I need

Comment: What policy? Please show it in your Question and tell us why it "does not work as you need". The Bucket Policy can make all objects in the bucket (or in a sub-folder) accessibly publicly to anyone on the Internet, regardless of the ACL on the object.

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "S3:*",
                            ],
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I failed to provide web access to the objects in the bucket using the policy.
But I do not rule out that this is the right option. I will be very kind if you can suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2):

> The following example policy grants the `s3:GetObject` permission to any public anonymous users. This permission **allows anyone to read the object data**, which is useful for when you configure your bucket as a website and want everyone to be able to read objects in the bucket. Before you use a bucket policy to grant read-only permission to an anonymous user, **you must disable block public access settings** for your bucket.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this is a **Bucket Policy** that is added to the **Bucket**, not the IAM User.

In your comments above, you provided this policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "S3:*",
            ],
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy does not have a `Principal`, which makes me think that you were attempting to add it to an IAM User rather than a Bucket.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I admit that they are correct and can help.

I solved the current problem by changing my ci job with https://github.com/marketplace/actions/s3-sync
========
As for the Principal, I did not understand what the problem was, but this element is not available.